# How to create a simple firebase search querie in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

As i want to implement a search where if someone type the year of birth in searchbar then all candidate which all are born on that specific year will be displayed in my recycler View.

ItemsActivity

```
class ItemsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mStorage:FirebaseStorage? = null
    private var mDatabaseRef:DatabaseReference? = null
    private var  mDBListener:ValueEventListener? = null
    private lateinit var mCandidate:MutableList<Candidate>
    private lateinit var listAdapter:ListAdapter

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityItemsBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding= ActivityItemsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.rvList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.rvList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ItemsActivity)
        binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mCandidate = ArrayList()
        listAdapter = ListAdapter(this@ItemsActivity,mCandidate)
        binding.rvList.adapter = listAdapter
        /**set Firebase Database*/
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("candidate_upload")
        mDBListener = mDatabaseRef!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ItemsActivity,error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                mCandidate.clear()
                for (teacherSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val upload = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Candidate::class.java)
                    upload!!.key = teacherSnapshot.key
                    mCandidate.add(upload)

                }
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.GONE

            }

        })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mDatabaseRef!!.removeEventListener(mDBListener!!)
    }

}
```

[image: My database]
just search a lot a question but does not match my requirement please help me out  with these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format in which you currently store `dob` does not allow searching for the year. You could in your current format search for everyone born on the 20th with:

```
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("candidate_upload")
Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("dob").startAt("20/").endAt("20~")
mDBListener = query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
```

Now that's of course not a very common use-case, but unfortunately Firebase only has these `startAt` and `endAt` type operations.

So the trick is to store your dates in a format that allows the query:

```
"dob": "2002-04-20"
```

This is [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) that makes it easier to deal with dates. For example, we can now query everyone born in 2002 with:

```
Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("dob").startAt("2002/").endAt("2002~")
```

*The `~` is the above is not an operator of Firebase, but just the last printable ASCII character.*

Comment: what should i add in onDataChange and onCancelled?

Comment: My answer doesn't change anything about that. If you're still having trouble retrieving the data, I recommend setting a breakpoint in `onDataChange`, running in the debugger, seeing if it hits the breakpoint, and if so step through the code from there.