# Firebase query not working properly,not showing desired result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

As I have created a simple query that short the data according to candidate DOB,
if the user enters any particular year then this search query has to give a candidate which is born on that particular year in a recyclerView but it doesn't. as I do not receive any error but the code does not work as expected above

code along with the search query

```
class ItemsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mStorage:FirebaseStorage? = null
    private var mDatabaseRef:DatabaseReference? = null
    private var  mDBListener:ValueEventListener? = null
    private lateinit var mCandidate:MutableList<Candidate>
    private lateinit var listAdapter:ListAdapter

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityItemsBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding= ActivityItemsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.rvList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.rvList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ItemsActivity)
        binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mCandidate = ArrayList()
        listAdapter = ListAdapter(this@ItemsActivity,mCandidate)
        binding.rvList.adapter = listAdapter
//        /**set Firebase Database*/
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("candidate_upload")
        mDBListener = mDatabaseRef!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ItemsActivity,error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                mCandidate.clear()
                for (teacherSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val upload = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Candidate::class.java)
                    upload!!.key = teacherSnapshot.key
                    mCandidate.add(upload)

                }
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.GONE

            }

        })
//        //search query
        val search=binding.etsearch.text.toString()
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("candidate_upload")
         val query = mDatabaseRef!!.orderByChild("dob").startAt(search).endAt(search)
        mDBListener = query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (teacherSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val upload = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Candidate::class.java)
                    upload!!.key = teacherSnapshot.key
                    mCandidate.add(upload)

                }
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ItemsActivity,error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                binding.pbLoding.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        })
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mDatabaseRef!!.removeEventListener(mDBListener!!)
    }
}
```

model

```
data class Candidate(
    var name: String? = null,
    var fathers_name: String? = null,
    var gender: String? = null,
    var dob: String? = null,
    var time_place: String? = null,
    var qualification: String? = null,
    var job: String? = null,
    var Height: String? = null,
    var fathers_qualification: String? = null,
    var requirement: String? = null,
    var address: String? = null,
    var contact: String? = null,
    var imageUrl:String?=null,
    @get:Exclude
    @set:Exclude
    var key: String? =null
)
```

database structure
[[image: 1]

[image: emulator]

As have entered 2000 so the candidate which is born in that particular year should be displayed in that recyclerView, but not getting the desired result.
please someone help me out with these that would be a great help thank you.

Comment: dharmaraj do you have any idea what wrong with the code ?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and also add the content of your Candidate class.

Comment: Alex Mamo I have made changes please help me out with these.

Comment: You don't seem to have changed your date format as I said in the answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954994/how-to-create-a-simple-firebase-search-querie-in-kotlin. That explains why your query doesn't work.